# What’s killing my plants?

Tags: houseplants, diseases, succulents, fungus, roots

I am desperate for some good advice please. Three of my favorite houseplants are suffering terribly. My Bunny Ears cactus, Hens & Chicks cactus, as well as my snake plant are all affected.

I’m in Ohio, and I just brought all my houseplants back inside for the season. That’s when I noticed how affected they are. There seems to be a white, powdery substance near the root on a couple of sections, but other than that, I don’t see anything abnormal. It’s just like the roots are dying from the inside out. For instance, the Hen& Chicks, all the offshoots that connect the main plant, are just black inside. The snake plant, which is the only one of the 3 that’s not a succulent or cactus, seems to have just had its roots disappear. The above ground part of the plant, is just laying on the dirt, or appears to be still standing, as it leans on the other rootless part. The plants are all in their own planters. And I’ve had the snake plant for nearly 10 years and the cactus several as well. Everywhere I look online I see different answers.

[image: cactus with damage]

and more here

https://photos.app.goo.gl/z9ZCfw3kqA9zaUxD8

Comment: A photo would help with diagnosis.

Comment: I took a few pictures, but I can’t figure out how to load them on here?

Comment: I was able to add a link to the photos of the problem.

Comment: The link is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing as "powdery" gives me the idea that this may be a fungal disease called powdery mildew. They may have contracted it outside your home from another plant that was infected and spread it's spores. You can get an organic/inorganic fungicide and spray the affected area to see if that helps. I have had plants with this disease before, just give them a good spray of some sort of fungicide.

Comment: I was able to add a link to the photos of the issues. I am repotting in new soil and I sprayed them down with Neem Oil Soap.